# How to get the information from table to another page using PHP and MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have problem in connecting the information from the table to the other page. The table consists of information and there's a button to the right side named "View Information." When the user click the button, it will redirect to *view_order.php*. Inside the *view_order.php*, is the information in the table.

Please help me to figure this out. :)

```
<?php
session_start();
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','sampsix');
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo 'Failed to connect: '.mysqli_connect_error();
}

if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
    $DeleteQuery = "DELETE FROM orders WHERE id='$_POST[hidden]'";
    mysqli_query($conn,$DeleteQuery);
}
if(isset($_POST['view'])){
    header('Location: view_order.php');
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM orders ORDER BY id";
$results = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

echo '<table border="1">';
    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<th>ID</th>';
        echo '<th>Firstame</th>';
        echo '<th>Lastname</th>';
        echo '<th>Email</th>';
        echo '<th>Order Name</th>';
        echo '<th>Order Code</th>';
        echo '<th>Order Qty</th>';
        echo '<th>Sub Total</th>';
    echo '</tr>';

    while($orderData = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
        echo '<form action="order.php" method="POST">';
        echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$orderData['id'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$orderData['firstname'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$orderData['lastname'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$orderData['email'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$orderData['ordername'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$orderData['ordercode'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$orderData['orderqty'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$orderData['subtotal'].'</td>';

            echo '<td><input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="'.$orderData['id'].'"></td>';
            echo '<td><input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete"></td>';
            echo '<td><input type="submit" name="view" value="View Order"></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '</form>';
    }


echo '</table>';

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Here is the code of view_order.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once('config.php');

if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];

$query = $mysqli->query("SELECTid,firstname,lastname,email,ordername,ordercode,orderqty,subtotal FROM orders WHERE id='$id'");

if($query){
        while($obj = $query->fetch_object()){
            echo 'id: '.$obj->id;
            echo 'Firstname: '.$obj->firstname;
            echo 'Lastname: '.$obj->lastname;
            echo 'Email: '.$obj->email;
            echo 'Order Name: '.$obj->ordername;
            echo 'Order Code: '.$obj->ordercode;
            echo 'Order Qty: '.$obj->orderqty;
            echo 'Sub Total: '.$obj->subtotal;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

None appears on the view_order.php. If there's error in my codes, please check it and suggest.

Comment: usually when someone says `help figure this out`, they explain a specific problem first ( with details). Where is your problem description? You need to be far more specific than what you've stated so far

Comment: The view_order.php nothing appears on my notepad. Here is my code.

Comment: Where is the code for view_order.php ?

Comment: <?php
 session_start();
 include_once('config.php');
 
 if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
  $id = $_SESSION['id'];
  
  $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT id,firstname,lastname,email,ordername,ordercode,orderqty,subtotal FROM orders WHERE id='$id'");
  
  if($query){
   while($obj = $query->fetch_object()){
    echo 'Firstname: '.$obj->firstname;
   }
  }
 }
 }
?>

Comment: edit your question not drop unformatted code in a comment block where nobody can read it

Comment: @DeanilVicente..Why you are using form for this?

Comment: `query("SELECTid,firstname,` that does nothing; it's a syntax error.

Comment: Sir @Fred -ii- mr. Jenz already answer this. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that FORM is needed in case. As I understood what you need is to redirect to the detailed page when you click View button. Instead of button, you can use hyperlink and pass the id through URL.

```
  while($orderData = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
       // echo '<form action="order.php" method="POST">';
        echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$orderData['id'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$orderData['firstname'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$orderData['lastname'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$orderData['email'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$orderData['ordername'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$orderData['ordercode'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$orderData['orderqty'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$orderData['subtotal'].'</td>';

           // echo '<td><input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="'.$orderData['id'].'"></td>';
            //echo '<td><input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete"></td>';
            echo "<td><a href='view_order.php?id=".$orderData['id']."'>View</a></td>";
        echo '</tr>';
        //echo '</form>';
    }
```

and in view_order.php

```
<?php
include_once('config.php');

if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];

$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT id,firstname,lastname,email,ordername,ordercode,orderqty,subtotal FROM orders WHERE id='$id'");

if($query){
        while($obj = $query->fetch_object()){
            echo 'Firstname: '.$obj->firstname;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Sir/maam I need the form for the "Delete" button.

Comment: @DeanilVicente..You can do the same for delete also. May be you can use another page for delete code or in the same order.php page you can do it.

Comment: Or sure. Wait @Jenz I'll try your codes if it will run. if not, I'll tell you.

Comment: Is the value getting appeared in url? If so try to echo that id from url

Comment: No value @Jenz. And also where is the button to redirect I can't find the button in your codes. :(

Comment: @DeanilVicente..Why you need buttons. You can use hyperlink (`<a>`) tag instead.

Comment: `<a href='view_order.php?id=".$orderData['id']."'>View</a>` This link will redirect to view_order.php with id in URL.

Comment: Okay @Jenz but still I can't find the link on the table :(

Comment: YES YES YES!!! I've Got your point! And you already fixed it @Jenz. :D hahaha I forgot to put "View" between the <a> tag. :D

Comment: haha How to accept the answer? haha sorry I'm a newbie her. :D

Comment: @DeanilVicente..Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/tour to know more about stackoverflow.

Comment: hahah sorry for the mean time. Stack overflow says I need to 15 reputation to vote up. :)

Comment: @DeanilVicente..That is okay :) No problem with that. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261079/how-to-get-initial-reputation-in-stackoverflow